# This is not working in jquery function

Tags: jquery, overlay, this

I'm having certain items on my page. When someone hovers an item, I'd like an overlay div over that item. This is working if I'm using the function without `$(this)`, but then it's overlaying all the items. I would like to only overlay the item that I'm hovering at that moment.

My code:

jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".item" , function() {
    $(this).('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
  });
  $(document).on("mouseleave", ".item" , function() {
    $(this).('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <a href="#"><img src="<?=$row['item_pic']?>" class="item-img"></a>
  <div class="item-overlay" style="background:#999; display: none; position:absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width:400px; height:200px; z-index:900;">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(this)  referencing document i think ..

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(this).('.item-overlay')
```

is invalid, and should probably be:

```
$(this).find('.item-overlay')
```

In total:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).find('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        },    
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).find('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
        }
    }, '.item');
});
</script>
```

just for fun, here's a shorter version:

```
$(function() {
  $(this).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.item', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.item-overlay')[e.type=='mouseenter'?'fadeIn':'fadeOut'](250);
  });
});
```

Comment: To comment on this solution, you either need to have your code at the bottom of the page or use this type of solution that is a short form of jquerys ready function, found at http://api.jquery.com/ready/ that waits for the page to load before executing.

Comment: @fanfavorite - Did you not notice the DOM ready function? It's been there all along, and does exactly what you're commenting about ?

Comment: I know, I was just explaining more to the user with your solution. :)

Comment: @fanfavorite - Oh okey, just so used to peeps pointing out errors, did'nt realize it was an explaination until I read it again. Thank you then :) !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item" , function() {
    $(this).children('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".item" , function() {
    $(this).children('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
});
```

});

needed "children"

Answer (score 0):

Try out this script:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item" , function() {
    $('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".item" , function() {
    $('.item-overlay').stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
});
```

**I just removed the $(this)**

**Hope it helped**

Comment: This code will fade all of the items with class item-overlay instead of the element associated with the item.

Comment: check out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/tdf6g/
the box is only coming at the top because of the positioning!